# Pandas add new columns in subloops back to the main dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
 ids    value   
  1      0.1
  1      0.2
  1      0.14   
  2      0.22
    ....
```

I am trying to loop through each ids and calculate new columns for each id.

```
for id, row in df.groupby('ids'):
    x = row.loc[0, 'value']

    for i in range (len(row)):
        row.loc[i, 'new_col_1'] = i * x
        row.loc[i, 'new_col_2'] = i * x * 10
```

My goal is to add the 2 new columns for each id back to the original dataframe, so my df would look like this:

```
 ids    value    new_col_1     new_col_2
  1      0.1       0              0
  1      0.2       0.2            2
  1      0.14      0.28           2.8
  2      0.22      0              0
     ....
```

Comment: @piRSquared it was a mistake, thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1):

#### `cumcount`

With a little Numpy broadcasting sprinkled in.

- `cumcount` gets you your `for i in range(len(df))` bit

  ```
  df.groupby('ids').cumcount()

  0    0
  1    1
  2    2
  3    0
  dtype: int64
  ```

---

```
c = df.groupby('ids').cumcount()
v = df.value

df.join(
    pd.DataFrame(
      (c.values * v.values)[:, None] * [1, 10],
      df.index,
  ).rename(columns=lambda x: f"new_col_{x + 1}")
)

   ids  value  new_col_1  new_col_2
0    1   0.10       0.00        0.0
1    1   0.20       0.20        2.0
2    1   0.14       0.28        2.8
3    2   0.22       0.00        0.0
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the new columns using the existing loop?

Comment: I'm sure you could.  But why would you want to use a loop when you don't have to.

Comment: I want to do more data multiplication in the for loop with the indexes. I still couldn't figure out how to merge the new columns back to the original df. I tried merge with pd.concat.